# MDX weighted values

Tags: mdx, pivot-table, olap, cube

I have a cube built on a fact which, amongst others, includes the Balance and Percentage columns.  I have a calculation which multiplies the Balance by the Percentage to obtain an Adjusted Value.  I now need to have this Adjusted Value divided by the sum of all balances, to get weighted values.

The problem is that this sum of all balances doesn't apply to the whole dataset.  Rather, it should be calculated on a filtered subset of the whole data.  This filtering is being done in Excel using a pivot table, so i do not know what conditions will be used to filter.

So, for example, this would be the pivot i'd like to see:

```
ID   Balance   Percentage   Adjusted Value   Weighted Adjusted Value
1    100       1.5          115              0.38 (ie 115/300)
2    50        2            51               0.17 (ie 51/300)
3    150       1            150              0.50 (ie 150/300)
```

300 is obtained by summing the balance of the rows that show in the filtered pivot.

Can this calculation be somehow done in OLAP?  Or is it impossible to compute this sum with what i know?

Answer (score 0):

Yes should be possible; e.g., assuming 1/2/3 are the children of a common parent, then the following calculated measure should do the trick :

```
WAV = AV / ( id.parent, Balance )
```

If not we would need more information about the actual data model and query.